# Why akka http can use method path without extend the trait?

Tags: scala, akka

by the akka http example:https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/introduction.html#using-akka-http

```
object WebServer {
val route =
      path("hello") {
        get {
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
        }
      }
```

the path is a method defined in trait PathDirectives:

```
trait PathDirectives extends PathMatchers with ImplicitPathMatcherConstruction with ToNameReceptacleEnhancements {

def path[L](pm: PathMatcher[L]): Directive[L] = pathPrefix(pm ~ PathEnd)
```

so isn't WebServer will use the method path,it have to extend the trait PathDirectives?why there needn't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to extend anything if you use correct import statement.

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
```

This brings all methods defined in object `Directives`

```
object Directives extends Directives

trait Directives extends RouteConcatenation
  with BasicDirectives
  with CacheConditionDirectives
  with CookieDirectives
  with DebuggingDirectives
  with CodingDirectives
  with ExecutionDirectives
  with FileAndResourceDirectives
  with FileUploadDirectives
  with FormFieldDirectives
  with FutureDirectives
  with HeaderDirectives
  with HostDirectives
  with MarshallingDirectives
  with MethodDirectives
  with MiscDirectives
  with ParameterDirectives
  with TimeoutDirectives
  with PathDirectives
  with RangeDirectives
  with RespondWithDirectives
  with RouteDirectives
  with SchemeDirectives
  with SecurityDirectives
  with WebSocketDirectives
  with FramedEntityStreamingDirectives
```

which includes `PathDirectives` too

Comment: Thanks.but if I write a simple prog in floder:/src/main/scala 
A.scala 
object A extends App with C{
  val x=e(1)
} 
C.scala
trait C {
  def e(x:Int)={println("a")}
}
in this simple prog,there is no need to import anything,but I need to write "with C"so I can write val x=e(1)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If you want to use path or any other directive, you need to either use import statement or extend Directives trait.

Comment: if you create `object C extends C` (companion object that extends trait C), you may just import it to be able to use methods defined in trait C.